# Custom fields in Laravel scoping

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent model with a relationship and a scope for that relationship

```
<?php

namespace App;
...

class Shift extends Model
{
    public function profession()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profession::class, 'id', 'profession');
    }
    ...
    public function scopeWithProfession($query)
    {
        $query->with('profession');
    }
...
}
```

Then, in my controller, I just call this scope as follows, and it gives me the fields in the professions table:

```
public function show(Shift $shift)
{
    return Shift::where('id', $shift->id)->withProfession()->first();
}
```

Now, my profession item has a self-referencing foreign key that assigns an optional parent object to a profession instance

```
Schema::create('professions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('color');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('parent_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('professions');
    });
```

What I want to achieve, is in the call to the withProfession scope, I also want to return a field that references the name of the parent object as an extra to the normal fields in the profession table. This means I essentially need to "add" a custom field to the withProfession scope. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

there is a simple solution but it load the whole parent:
the base idea is to define a parentProfession relation in Profession Model
then load it in with inside your scope ...

```
class Profession extends Model
{
    public function parentProfession()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profession::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}


class Shift extends Model
{
    public function profession()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profession::class, 'id', 'profession');
    }
    ...
    public function scopeWithProfession($query)
    {
        $query->with('profession.parentProfession');
    }
...
}
```

this should load the Profession with it's parent ...
if you has to get only the name, then you have to a chain of join with 'addSelect'